# steps to terminate a shell

Tags: glibc, job-control

I've read the chapter about the job control in the `glibc` manual, but I'm wondering what to do with the remaining jobs when the shell is terminated.

I suppose the following steps (following the convention of posix to handle orphaned process groups the first two steps seems obvious):

- send an HUP signal to the jobs with the shell's sid
- send a CONTINUE signal to the stopped jobs  with the shell's sid
- free up the resource allocated for the job's data structures

My problem is what if the jobs survive?

I thought that a chance would be changing their session id to free up the sid  and disassociate the process group from the terminal (not sure if that makes sense)

Should I do `ioctl(STDIN_FILENO, TIOCSCTTY)` to make the session processes lose the controlling terminal and send the signals?

What to do with the `tty`? Should I launch a login and set it as a new controlling terminal process group of the tty?

I'm still confused and a clue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> send an HUP signal to the jobs with the shell's sid

No need for that. The kernel will send a HUP signal itself when the shell (the session leader) terminates.

> send a CONT signal to the stopped jobs with the shell's sid

No need for that. The kernel will send it for you, too ;-)

> free up the resource allocated for the job's data structures

No need for that, either. All resources used by a process will be freed up by the kernel when the process terminates.

> My problem is what if the jobs survive?

I guess you can `SIGKILL` them, if that's really a problem. In unix, they're *supposed* to survive, if they handle `SIGHUP`.

The "modern" systemd takes a different approach, completely against that spirit, but I would not enter into that ;-)

**Notes:**

In linux, it's the [`kill_orphaned_pgrp()`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/5929a1f0ff30d04ccf4b0f9c648e7aa8bc816bbd/kernel/exit.c#L372) from `kernel/exit.c` which is responsible for sending the `HUP`+`CONT` to all stopped jobs from the session, and [`tty_signal_session_leader()`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/5929a1f0ff30d04ccf4b0f9c648e7aa8bc816bbd/drivers/tty/tty_jobctrl.c#L179) from `drivers/tty/tty_jobctl.c`, called via `tty_vhangup_session()` and `__tty_hangup()` which is resposible for sending the HUP to the processes from the foreground process group.

Comment: Hi mosvy, the kernel sends the signals HUP and CONT but for whom process? It could be the root process or the shell code that takes care to send the signal...
I don't think that is wrapped in the kernel code, but I could be wrong..   
I'm going to deep in the systemd approach too, if you get the chance to explain I'm really interested..
Thanks a lot for your help/time

Comment: no, the kernel sends it to all processes from the session. I'd five you a kernel source link, but editing on a phone is no fun. Check it with strace

Comment: I checked out the bash code in my launch time. Although I don't have an overall comprehension of the code, I suppose the involved code should be in the functions:

void exit_shell (s) @ shell.c

void hangup_all_jobs () @ jobs.c

the code loops over the jobs table and send the signals with the following instructions:

   killpg (jobs[i]->pgrp, SIGHUP);
   if (STOPPED (i))
     killpg (jobs[i]->pgrp, SIGCONT);

So bash should take care of sending its jobs the signals on exit.
Tonight I will try to strace..

Comment: That is very bash-specific, non standard (`shopt -s huponexit`). Other shells (eg. `dash` don't implement that). You don't have to replicate it, either. If you don't believe me, start a command like `(trap '' HUP; exec sleep 10000)`, then attach to `sleep` with strace from another window, and kill the parent shell with SIGKILL; sleep will still receive the SIGHUP and SIGCONT.

Comment: Brilliant! Trap nullifies the HUP signal, exec replaces the subshell with sleep. Strace ouput shows that the signal is sent by the kernel (si_code=SI_KERNEL). See sigaction(2) manpage.

Strace logs is as follows: restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted nanosleep ...>) = ? ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK (Interrupted by signal) --- SIGHUP {si_signo=SIGHUP, si_code=SI_KERNEL} --- restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted restart_syscall ...> <detached ...> 

I will deep in the tty driver code in these days. This is very challenging for me. Thanks again, you help me a lot!

Comment: If `SIGHUP` is sent by a kernel, why exiting a remote shell leaves a background `sleep` process on a server (`ssh server`, `sleep 10000 &`, Ctrl-D, `ssh server`, `pgrep sleep`)?

Comment: Like in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84737/in-which-cases-is-sighup-not-sent-to-a-job-when-you-log-out) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6337/29867).

Answer (score 0):

- Should I launch a login and set it as a new controlling terminal process group of the tty?

I read up and I think the answer should be no.

For a character based terminal, the root process (initd/systemd/launchd etc) forks and execs getty for the preconfigured terminals or at a specific event.
Getty opens the terminal files for read/write and associates the std file descriptors to the terminal, sets a simple environment from a configuration file and prompts for a username, then execs login for that username.
Login changes the ownership and permission rights for the terminal, changes the persona of the process (effective and real uid, gid, supplement groups), and execs a login shell
When a shell terminates, its parent process get notified by a sigchd, and relaunches getty... 
So the tty initialization/destruction is not a task for the shell..

Yet not sure on how to treat the survived process groups..