# Resume execution of python process after killing parent

Tags: python, process, subprocess

I'm sorry if this has been asked before - I just don't know how to search for the right answer and would be very thankful for a pointer.

I'm trying to do the following in Python (on Linux):

```
import psutil
from time import sleep
from subprocess import run
from shlex import split

psutil.Process().parent().kill()
sleep(3)
run(split('touch /home/tobias/foo'))
```

In other words, trying to kill the parent process but resume the child process and execute some logic after the parent process has been killed.

But as it stands, the file is not created. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you run this code in terminal, your parent process will be `shell`(`bash` is default shell in my system). If `session leader` (which is `shell` in this context) that has a controlling terminal die, then `SIGHUP` signal is sent by linux kernel **to each process in the foreground job**, and the controlling terminal is disassociated from that session. To get more info please look at [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Internals.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53268809/steps-to-terminate-a-shell/53291762#53291762)

Yes, `SIGHUP` signal will be send to your process by linux kernel and your process will terminate, that's why your `run(split('touch /home/tobias/foo'))`  will not work. We can prevent to terminate your process using signal handler like :

```
import psutil
from time import sleep
from subprocess import run
from shlex import split

import signal

def handler(signum,frame):
    print("got {} signal".format(signal.Signals(signum).name), file = open('out.txt', 'a+'))

psutil.Process().parent().kill()
sleep(3)
run(split('touch /home/tobias/foo'))
```